# Toilet water tank sometimes takes hours to fill and sometimes it fill up right away

Tags: toilet

As stated above, sometimes the tank takes hours to fill and other it fills up in a minute or less. This has been happening now for weeks and I had no changes made recently, it started all of a sudden. Thanks.

Comment: The fill valve may have some scale chunks blocking it. Some are designed to be cleaned. Turn the supply off flush the toilet and see if the cap can be released on the top of the valve. Some twist off some have clips. If it is removable put a jar or coffee cup on top and turn the water on and move the float up and down. Make sure to keep the jar or cup over the valve to keep the water from spraying all over the bathroom. Turn the water off and reassemble. Some of the floats will come out with the arm off. If this clears it great if not you may need to replace the valve assembly about 15$

Answer (score 2):

Your problem could be a flapper valve that does not always seat down tight on the flush drain at the bottom of the toilet water tank. This can cause a small flow of water to continue to drain from the tank as it attempts to fill. Sometimes the flapper will plop down in the correct position and allow the tank to fill normally.

In the leaking case, as the tank does start to slowly fill, the water pressure from above will try to push the flapper valve to a fully closed position thus starting to close off the leak and eventually allowing the tank to fill up.

Flapper valves, despite the claims from the manufacturer, can react with the water and become either hardened or start to decompose to a rubbery gunk. *(Even with the best ones I can purchase I need to replace mine about once every one to two years).* Both of these cases can lead to the flapper valve seating problem like I describe above. The fix is to purchase a new one. Typical install is easy and usually takes all of 5 minutes. There may be some extra time to adjust the chain from the flush lever to get it operate correctly. Chain too long and it can get under the flapper and create a leak and too short and the lever tugs on the flapper putting undue stress on the part of the flapper where the chain attaches.

Comment: I second this one. If it's intermittent, it's most likely the flapper.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention lots of water running in the bowl (and when I have that problem from the flapper/flush valve it NEVER fills until it's fixed): I have one of the "modern" no-ball-arm fill valves that will stick closed sometimes. Generally taking the lid off the tank and giving it a sharp rap will get it back to filling. Ultimately I'll replace it when that gets to be too much of an annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

The Filler valve could be causing your problem or the flapper could be causing it.

The Filler valve is a cheap and easy fix. Skip the arm and ball float type and get the unit with the float on the filler valve shaft.

The Flapper could be leaking - you will hear it or see it drizzling - if you can not determine that add a bit of green or blue food coloring to the tank water - if it appears in your t-bowl you will know the flapper is leaking. Get a replacement kit - they are cheap enough and easy enough to install. A Novice can do both in about an hour, someone who has done it before - less than 30 minutes.